# Copying specific values to a separate column

Tags: excel, function, copy

I have an excel sheet with 6 columns `A,B,C,D,E,F,G`

The sheet gives an overview of states and cities.

My problem is that column `C` (region) contains names of states and cities.
Every time the name of a state is displayed, cities will follow beneath in this same column.
Column `E` contains values **state** or **city**. 
If column `C` has value **name of a state** `E` has value *state*, if it has **a name of a city** `E` has value **city**

What I want is every city followed by a separate column:**Statename**.
I am looking for a function when `E` has value **state** the value in `C` 'Name of the state will be copied to  a separate column **Statename** behind each cityname

[image: Cities and states]

Comment: upvote, encourage to update image.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
IF(B2="state", "", IF(B1="state",A1,C1))
```

[image]